# getAssets in app widget

Tags: android

My app widget use a database, and it's preloaded in asset directory which activity copy it to database directory on first run.

But if widget is inserted before that, an exception is thrown as the database doesn't exist yet.

Is there anyway the widget check for the file and if it doesn't exist, get it from assets and copy it instead of activity?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend [using `SQLiteAssetHelper` for packaging databases in an app](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). You can then use `getReadableDatabase()`/`getWriteableDatabase()` as normal, and `SQLiteAssetHelper` will transparently unpack your database from assets if needed.

That being said, if you are sure that you want to do this yourself, call `getAssets()` on the `Context` passed into `onUpdate()` of your `AppWidgetProvider`.

Note that `onUpdate()` of your `AppWidgetProvider` is called on the main application thread, so just like you are (hopefully) doing your activity database I/O in a background thread, you should do the same for your app widget. A typical solution for an app widget is to have the work be done by an `IntentService` started by `onUpdate()`.

Comment: I read it from here http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ suggested by some pals over here. Thank you for the information

Comment: @Ali: That blog post is very old and was written before `SQLiteAssetHelper` was available.

Comment: Thank you, anyway I don't think I can use that, because I use the database in my app and as a websql in a webview, which I don't think it supports.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by background thread? I do it just in onUpdate and it works. Must I do it in another thread or service? I didn't and couldn't find anything regarding this. I will be so thankful if you guide me.

Comment: @Ali: "Must I do it in another thread or service?" -- you are freezing your UI while you do database I/O in the main application thread. This is considered bad form, particularly from your activity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will move it.